# GraphFrame Spark : Get Subgraph from specific node

Tags: scala, apache-spark, graph, spark-graphx, graphframes

I'm building an simple Graph with GraphFrames on Scala 2.11 Spark 2.2.

I can create my graph without problems, but i have no idea how create a subgraph from input user.

I want to extract graph from the big one, like :

> Get subgraph from node#123 with 3 max depth parents.

I tried connectedComponent, ( see https://graphframes.github.io/user-guide.html ) but I have no idea what to do with "compenent" column.

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Hey. 
I switched to Neo4J backend. With Neo4J, I used 
https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-spark-connector to request my graph.

You can do cypher Neo4J request in Spark and load them in GraphFrames.

So, I made Cypher request to get my SubGraph in Neo4J and load them to GraphFrames.

With GraphFrames solo, I didnt't succed sorry :)

Goold luck.